# How to fix Property overflow-y doesn't exist in CSS level 2.1?

Tags: html, css, w3c-validation

How can I fix the following CSS error?

> Property overflow-y doesn't exist in CSS level 2.1 but exists in [css3] : scroll

Is it ok to replace

```
html {  overflow-y: scroll; }
```

with

```
html{   overflow: scroll; }
```

Validated code : http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.santiagomichalek.com%2Fmanage.php&profile=css21&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en

Comment: I want you to read that error message and tell me how you're interpreting it. It doesn't seem that you've read it at all.

Answer (score 0):

No. As the error message says, the `overflow-y` (and `overflow-x`) do not exist in CSS specs prior to 3. CSS 2.1 only has `overflow`, which affects both axes, so `* { overflow-y: scroll; }` will give you the same error.

The latter option will work but will also affect the X axis, thus enforcing the horizontal scrollbar as well.

Comment: what about html {
 overflow: scroll;
} ?

Comment: @JohnK: Yes, that will take effect in CSS2.1 but may not be what the OP expects.